# Error (Xcode): Cycle inside Runner; building could produce unreliable results

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart

i'm trying to run flutter project on IOS simulator i got the following error:

```
Error (Xcode): Cycle inside Runner; building could produce unreliable results.
Cycle details:
→ Target 'Runner': CodeSign /Users/asmaalkhaldi/Desktop/Brmjha/tajiduh-1/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app
○ That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”
○ Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Users/asmaalkhaldi/Desktop/Brmjha/tajiduh-1/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/AthkarWidgetExtension.appex' to '/Users/asmaalkhaldi/Desktop/Brmjha/tajiduh-1/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/PlugIns/AthkarWidgetExtension.appex'
○ That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “Thin Binary”
○ Target 'Runner' has process command with output '/Users/asmaalkhaldi/Desktop/Brmjha/tajiduh-1/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Info.plist'
○ Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Users/asmaalkhaldi/Desktop/Brmjha/tajiduh-1/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/AthkarWidgetExtension.appex' to '/Users/asmaalkhaldi/Desktop/Brmjha/tajiduh-1/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/PlugIns/AthkarWidgetExtension.appex'
2

command: P0:target-Runner-18c1723432283e0cc55f10a6dcfd9e0288a783a885d8b0b3beb2e9f90bde3f49-:Debug:Copy /Users/asmaalkhaldi/Desktop/Brmjha/tajiduh-1/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/PlugIns/AthkarWidgetExtension.appex /Users/asmaalkhaldi/Desktop/Brmjha/tajiduh-1/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/AthkarWidgetExtension.appex
```

i tried moving embed framwork above run script in build phase tab[image: xcode build phases]
but i got the same error

Comment: You can try this order: Target Dependencies > Run Build Tool Plug-ins > Check Pods Manifest.lock > Embed Pods Frameworks > Embed Foundation Extensions > Crashlytics Upload Symbols > Run Script > Compile Sources > Link Binary With Libraries > Copy Bundle Resources > Thin Binary